# Subquery returns more than 1 row when have more than one value

Tags: mysql, select, subquery

It keeps giving me MySQL error Subquery returns more than 1 row when try to exceute this query

```
SELECT c.*,
    (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(o.project_extracts_total), 0)
     FROM extracts o
     WHERE o.project_id = c.id ) AS total_extracts,
    (SELECT contractor_evaluation   
     FROM project_extras s
     WHERE s.project_id = c.id
     ORDER BY ID DESC
     LIMIT 1) AS contractor_evaluation,
    (SELECT sum(order_value)    
     FROM orders o
     WHERE o.project_id = c.id) AS contract_final_value,
    (SELECT `transaction_number`
     FROM `orders` o 
     WHERE o.project_id = c.id
     AND 
     MONTH(`date_created`) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())
     AND YEAR(`date_created`) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())) AS transaction_number 
 FROM projects c
```

I found the problem in `orders` table when trying to get `transaction_number` when the project have more than `transaction_number` value like this

[image]

I want to have these values in query result row separated by comma like (1,15)

Comment: Use `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(transaction_number)`

Comment: any method to replace the comma , with another chatacter

Comment: Read the documentation, the separator is an optional parameter.